# How to move an attachment from one e-mail to another using MailKit/MimeKit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, email-attachments, mailkit, mimekit

If we have the `UniqueId` to the mail we wish to move the attachment to via the usage of an `ImapClient`, how exactly can we achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UniqueId? AddAttachmentToMessage (ImapClient client, ImapFolder folder, UniqueId uid, MimeEntity attachment)
{
    var message = folder.GetMessage (uid);
    var body = message.Body;
    Multipart multipart;

    if (message.Body is Multipart && message.Body.ContentType.IsMimeType ("multipart", "mixed")) {
        multipart = (Multipart) message.Body;
    } else {
        multipart = new Multipart ("mixed");
        multipart.Add (message.Body);
        message.Body = multipart;
    }

    multipart.Add (attachment);

    var newUid = folder.Append (message);
    folder.AddFlags (uid, MessageFlags.Deleted, true);

    if (client.Capabilities.HasFlag (ImapCapabilities.UidPlus))
        folder.Expunge (new UniqueId[] { uid });

    return newUid;
}
```

If the server doesn't support UIDPLUS and you need the `newUid` value, then you can probably do something like this:

```
if (!client.Capabilities.HasFlag (ImapCapabilities.UidPlus)) {
    var initialUids = folder.Search (SearchQuery.All);
    folder.Append (message);
    var updatedUids = folder.Search (SearchQuery.All);

    // find the new uids
    var newUids = new UniqueIdSet (SortOrder.Ascending);
    for (int i = updatedUids.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!initialUids.Contains (updatedUids[i]))
            newUids.Add (updatedUids[i]);
    }

    // get envelope info for each of the new messages
    var newItems = folder.Fetch (newUids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope);
    foreach (var item in newItems) {
        var msgid = MimeUtils.ParseMessageId (item.Envelope.MessageId);

        if (message.MessageId.Equals (msgid))
            return item.UniuqeId;

        // Note: if you want to be more pedantic, you can compare the From/To/Cc/ReplyTo and Subject fields as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: You're the best, thank you for making this amazing library and being so helpful to everyone that use it.

Comment: In the event `folder.Append(message)` returns a null `newUid`, what would be the best `SearchQuery` we could use to find the created mail's `UniqueId` via `folder.Search`? Is there something unique in a message we could use, or the best we could do is `SearchQuery.SubjectContains(message.Subject).And(SearchQuery.YoungerThan(400))` I used the number 400 in the event the server is busy or something - not sure if I'm accurate on that notion, but if there's no such danger I'd use a number like 40 as well.

Comment: I would imagine that if a server supports YOUNGER, it also supports UIDPLUS and so you'd get back a UID from the APPEND command. I'd probably recommend getting a list of UIDs prior to appending the message, then appending the message, then searching any new UIDs for the appended message.

Comment: Are there servers that don't even support `SubjectContains` as well as `DeliveredSince`? I'm guessing `NotDeleted` is supported everywhere, or even that is no guarantee and I should just stick to `SearchQuery.All` if I want maximum backwards compatibility?

Comment: In theory, all IMAP servers support SubjectContains, DeliveredSince, and NotDeleted (they are all part of the original spec). I didn't use them in my sample code because I didn't think they were really necessary (altho NotDeleted might be a good one) and because SubjectContains can be iffy in some IMAP server implementations. Using the 'ALL' query should be fast for all IMAP implementations, and since the code gets all UIDs before appending and then again after appending, there should hopefully only be 1 message anyway.

Comment: Seems `IMailFolder.Append` functions differently for Gmail - you don't simply "copy" the message, but rather you actually "reply" to the original message. Any idea how I can avoid this? As I'm moving attachments around, the outcome of it all is quite ugly, and it seems even though they support `UidPlus`, expunge doesn't seem to do anything, nor deleting? (For gmail I mean) Which is part of the reason the end result of my manipulations is an ugly, ugly conversation - if I could delete messages in the "reply" chain, it would look seamless as with other IMAP providers.

Comment: You should edit your IMAP settings in GMail to behave like a normal IMAP server. **When I mark a message in IMAP as deleted:** -> **Auto-Expunge off - Wait for the client to update the server.** and **When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder:** -> **Immediately delete the message forever**